# What is the difference between isomorphic-fetch and fetch?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, isomorphic-fetch-api

I've seen two different fetch here:

- https://github.com/github/fetch
- https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch

Can someone tell me the difference between the two?

PS: I've read the README.md but I still didn't get the difference. Last time I checked, Isomorphic means it has similar form or relation. It still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: For more alternatives, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433783/referenceerror-fetch-is-not-defined

Answer (score 122, accepted):

[FETCH](https://github.com/github/fetch) is polyfill for browsers which don't have fetch function ([caniuse.com/#search=fetch](http://caniuse.com/#search=fetch)). It will add fetch function to your browser window object.

While [isomorphic-fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch) is implementation of fetch for both node.js and browser, built on top of fetch polyfill.

Comment: so using isomorphic-fetch means, will it work for all browsers  just like polyfill?

Answer (score 2):

> The Fetch API is currently not implemented consistently across browsers. This module will enable you to use fetch in your Node code in a cross-browser compliant fashion.

Short answer, isomorphic fetch is a better way of using fetch because it covers a wide range of browsers than the native fetch API.