# How to make a rest post call from ReactJS code?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, reactjs-native

I am new to ReactJS and UI and I wanted to know how to make a simple REST based POST call from ReactJS code.

*If there is any example present it would be really helpful.*

Comment: Could you please choose the answer that helped you out?

Answer (score 252):

Straight from the [React Native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network):

```
fetch('https://mywebsite.example/endpoint/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: 'yourValue',
    secondParam: 'yourOtherValue',
  })
})
```

(This is posting JSON, but you could also do, for example, multipart-form.)

Also see docs for [ReactJS AJAX FAQs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) if not using React Native.

Comment: Thanks for the example :) but now I am getting another error 'cant find variable fetch'.Also I am totally new to React JS so I am not sure whether this is the correct way to do it                                                                       var APP = React.createClass ({

 render() {
 return ( fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/ui/start', {
  method: 'POST',
 
  body: JSON.stringify({
    Id: '112',
    User: 'xyz',
  })
})
 );
 }
});

Comment: You have to [install it and import it](https://github.com/github/fetch).  Don't forget, the `fetch()` function doesn't return the _data_, it just returns a [promise](https://www.promisejs.org/).

Comment: haha @Divya, I was just about to make the same comment before reading yours. Not sure whether or not to put it in React.createClass. Also, could we please have a link to the react docs? I tried to search their site (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html) unsuccessfully.

Comment: Can we please modify the original answer to include the import?

Comment: @user6582640 -- the import actually depends on exactly where you get `fetch()`.

Comment: Life saver #MalvloioYouTheRealMVP I wasn't using JSON.stringify #5hoursLater

Comment: IMO, @amann has a [better answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38512250/1003959). This answer implies `fetch` is built into React, which it is not, and there is no link to the docs referenced. `fetch` is (at time of writing) [an experimental Promise-based API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). For browser-compatibility, you'll need [a babel polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch).

Comment: Note, that this is from the React Native docs, not the React JS docs, but you may use Fetch_API in React JS as well. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html

Answer (score 29):

React doesn't really have an opinion about how you make REST calls. Basically you can choose whatever kind of AJAX library you like for this task.

The easiest way with plain old JavaScript is probably something like this:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', '/my/url', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
request.send(data);
```

In modern browsers you can also use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

If you have more components that make REST calls it might make sense to put this kind of logic in a class that can be used across the components. E.g. `RESTClient.post(…)`

Comment: To me, this is the best answer, because React doesn't have anything built in.  You either have to import `fetch` or `superagent` or `jQuery` or `axios` or something else that is not part of "vanilla React" in order to do anything other than what is posted above.

Comment: It looks like if you're using flask, it works well to do `JSON.stringify({"key": "val"})` and then on the flask side do `request.get_json()`

Comment: Yep, if you're posting JSON, you have to `JSON.stringify` it first.

Answer (score 23):

Another recently popular packages is : [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

Install : `npm install axios --save`

Simple Promise based requests

---

```
axios.post('/user', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 9):

you can install superagent

```
npm install superagent --save
```

then for make post call to server

```
import request from "../../node_modules/superagent/superagent";

request
.post('http://localhost/userLogin')
.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
.send({ username: "username", password: "password" })
.end(function(err, res){
console.log(res.text);
});
```

Answer (score 7):

As of 2018 and beyond, you have a more modern option which is to incorporate async/await in your ReactJS application. A promise-based HTTP client library such as axios can be used. The sample code is given below:

```
import axios from 'axios';
...
class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.onLogin = this.onLogin.bind(this);
        ...
    }
    async onLogin() {
        const { email, password } = this.state;
        try {
           const response = await axios.post('/login', { email, password });
           console.log(response);
        } catch (err) {
           ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: for some reason nodejs does interpret `await` - `SyntaxError: await is a reserved word (33:19)`

Comment: @prayagupd what version of node are you using?

Answer (score 5):

I think this way also a normal way. But sorry, I can't describe in English ((

```html
    submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(this.state)
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/questions',{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
    }).then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            console.log(error)
        })
    
}
```

https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/fetch-api/fetch-post.html

fetch('url/questions',{
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
        }).then(response => {
                console.log(response)
            })
            .catch(error =>{
                console.log(error)
            })

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://andrewhfarmer.com/ajax-libraries/) is a the list of ajax libraries comparison based on the features and support.
I prefer to use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch) for only client side development or [isomorphic-fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch) for using in both client side and server side development.

For more information on [isomorphic-fetch vs fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37936715/what-is-the-difference-between-isomorphic-fetch-and-fetch)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a util function modified (another post on stack) for get and post both. Make Util.js file.

```
let cachedData = null;
let cachedPostData = null;

const postServiceData = (url, params) => {
    console.log('cache status' + cachedPostData );
    if (cachedPostData === null) {
        console.log('post-data: requesting data');
        return fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(params)
          })
        .then(response => {
            cachedPostData = response.json();
            return cachedPostData;
        });
    } else {
        console.log('post-data: returning cachedPostData data');
        return Promise.resolve(cachedPostData);
    }
}

const getServiceData = (url) => {
    console.log('cache status' + cachedData );
    if (cachedData === null) {
        console.log('get-data: requesting data');
        return fetch(url, {})
        .then(response => {
            cachedData = response.json();
            return cachedData;
        });
    } else {
        console.log('get-data: returning cached data');
        return Promise.resolve(cachedData);
    }
};

export  { getServiceData, postServiceData };
```

Usage like below in another component

```
import { getServiceData, postServiceData } from './../Utils/Util';

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      datastore : []
    }
  }

componentDidMount = () => {  
    let posturl = 'yoururl'; 
    let getdataString = { name: "xys", date:"today"};  
    postServiceData(posturl, getdataString)
      .then(items => { 
        this.setState({ datastore: items }) 
      console.log(items);   
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple method to define and call post APIs in reactjs. Install `axios` using command `npm install axios` and call `post req` method wherever you want, it will return array that contains 100 elements.

```
// Define post_req() Method in authAction.js

import axios from 'axios';

const post_req = (data) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
const header = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
}
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    headers: header
 });
 .then((res)=>{resolve(res);})
 .catch((err)=>{reject(err);})
 })
}

// Calling post_req() Method in react component 
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { post_req } from 'path of file authAction.js'

class MyReactComponent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
 myList:[]
 };
}
componentDidMount() {
let data = {
 .......
 } 
 this.props.post_req(data)
 .then((resp)=>{this.setState({myList:resp.data})})
 .catch((err)=>{console.log('here is my err',err)})
}
render() {
return (
  <div>
    ....
  </div)
 }
}
export default MyReactComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

import React ,{useState}from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';

export  default function Formlp()
{

```
const url ="";

const [state, setstate] = useState({
    name:"",
    iduser:""
})

function handel(e){

    const newdata={...state}
    newdata[e.target.id]=e.target.value
    setstate(newdata);
}

function submit(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

  //  Axios.post(url,{name:state.name,iduser:state.iduser}).then( res=>{console.log(res)});

  console.log(state)

}
```

return (
<div onSubmit={ (e)=> submit(e)}>

<input onChange={  (e)=>handel(e) } id="name" value={state.name} placeholder="name" type="text" >
<input onChange={  (e)=>handel(e) } id="iduser" value={state.iduser} placeholder="iduser" type="text" >

```
        <button>submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

);
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example for v18+ while handling form data and creating a POST request with the data.

```
async function handleOrderSubmit(event){
  event.preventDefault()

  try{
    const formData= {name: event.target.name.value, email: event.target.email.value, message: event.target.name.message}
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData)
    };
    const response = await fetch('https://www.example.com/form', requestOptions);
    const data = await response.json();
    navigate("/form-response", { state: {data: data, status: true} })
  }
  catch(error){
    navigate("/form-response", { state: {status: false} })
  }
}
```

**Note 1:** Using `status` on '/form-response' page, you can customise what to show user. For true, you can show a different section and for false a different one.

**Note 2:** If the status is successful, you can access data on the next page also and customise it according to user information.

**Note 3:** `event.preventDefault()` is important to avoid page reloading.

Answer (score -6):

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/9888/

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/some/url',
    data: data
  })
  .done(function(result) {
    this.clearForm();
    this.setState({result:result});   
  }.bind(this)
  .fail(function(jqXhr) {
    console.log('failed to register');
  });
```

It used `jquery.ajax` method but you can easily replace it with AJAX based libs like axios, superagent or fetch.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example :) . I also wanted to understand if my service expects JSON format data.Then what changes would be required ? Any sort of information would be really helpful. So when I am using the curl command to hit the endpoint its like   curl -v -X POST http://localhost:8080/myapi/ui/start -d '{"Id":"112","User":"xyz"}'
 so how can I call such a service.

Comment: create a variable called data with `'{"Id":"112","User":"xyz"}'` and change the URL to  localhost:8080/myapi/ui/start , thats about it , once the XHR call is successful you will land on in the done method and you will have access to you data via the result property.