# How to send data from react to Controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reactjs, model-view-controller

I am new to react. I am trying to build a CRUD application with React and .NET MVC. I am able to find the code for only getting content from controller, but not for posting.

Below is the code for getting data from controller:

```
var App = React.createClass({

        getInitialState: function(){
            return{data: ''};
        },

        componentWillMount: function(){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', this.props.url, true);
        xhr.onload = function() {
          var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

          this.setState({ data: response.result });
        }.bind(this);
        xhr.send();
    },

        render: function(){
            return(
                <h1>{this.state.data}</h1>
            );
        }
});
```

Please provide me the code to send data from react to controller.

My data class:

```
public partial class EmployeeTable
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        public long Salary { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510640/how-to-make-a-rest-post-call-from-reactjs-code

Comment: how to obtain the transferred data in the controller?

Comment: do you have a class that contains the structure of the data you want to pass?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane yes. Ill include the class in the question.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, sent the data using [How to make a rest post call from ReactJS code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510640/how-to-make-a-rest-post-call-from-reactjs-code)

Now create an action in your controller

```
[HttpPost]
public void GetInfo([FromBody]EmployeeTable data){

}
```