# The url string is too long

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, web, url

I work with Excel and take a formula from a cell, then pair it into a tree object, then serialize it in JSON, and pass it to the URL so that my site on react takes this object in JSON and turns it back into a tree. But if the formula is too big, my URL becomes more than 2000 and an error occurs.

Working with Excel API via C#

```
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(res);
var url = "http://localhost:3000/CreateTreePage/?jsonString=" + json + "&lettersFormula" + lettersFormula;
```

Here is the code for React

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // Получение параметра jsonString из URL
    console.log(props);
    const { jsonString } = queryString.parse(window.location.search);
    console.log(jsonString)

    if (jsonString) {
      const formulasObjectsArray = JSON.parse(jsonString.replace(/\@/g, "#"));
      SetArray(formulasObjectsArray);
      console.log(formulasObjectsArray);
    }
  }, []);
```

Can I somehow transfer this data in another way, or can I compress it without loss?

Comment: You'd be better to use POST rather than GET (which you are currently using with URL).

Comment: @LeeTaylor But how do I read this request in React? I know I could send ajax from the react, but for that I already need this string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510640/how-to-make-a-rest-post-call-from-reactjs-code

Comment: @LeeTaylor But I take a line from the Excel application from the user on the PC, this is an Excel Add-in, I need a website on the react to display the tree. In fact, I don't have a backend

Comment: You would have to abandon your technique of reading the queryString if you go to another transfer method.  See if you can reduce the size using tricks [here](https://www.baeldung.com/json-reduce-data-size) (it's a java tutorial but the techniques should be similar in any language).