# fetch and Headers are undefined in IE11.0.9600 with babel-polyfill when process.env.NODE_ENV=='production'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, babeljs, fetch-api, babel-polyfill

When `process.env.NODE_ENV=='development'` - it is OK!

But our production build failed in IE 11 (11.0.9600).
All work fine in chrome 55.

devDependencies:

```
...
babel-core: "6.22.0",
babel-eslint: "^7.0.0",
babel-loader: "^6.2.5",
babel-preset-env: "^1.5.2",
babel-preset-es2015: "^6.16.0",
babel-preset-es2016: "^6.22.0",
babel-preset-es2017: "^6.16.0",
babel-preset-react: "^6.16.0",
babel-preset-stage-0: "^6.22.0"
...
```

dependencies:

```
...
babel-polyfill: "^6.16.0"
...
```

.babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "react",
        ["env", {
             "useBuiltIns": true
        }],
        "stage-0"
    ]
}
```

Try `"useBuiltIns": false`, es2016, es2015, es2017 presets. Nothing changes.

index.js:

```
"use strict";
import 'babel-polyfill'
...
```

webpack.config module.exports.entry:

```
vendor: ['babel-polyfill', 'immutable', 'react', 'react-dom', ...],
...
bundle: [path.resolve(__dirname, srcPath + ""index.js)]
```

vendor is the first script in index.html.

Typing _babelPolyfill in ie console return true.
But Headers, fetch are undefined...

Why `process.env.NODE_ENV=='production'` broke my app in IE11?
How to fix my config?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

core.js do not have polyfill for Headers() and fetch, so babel-polyfill don't.
Use one of fetch polyfills:

- whatwg-fetch polyfill for browsers only support https://github.com/github/fetch
- isomorphic-fetch - polyfill, based on whatwg-fetch, for node and browsers support

For more info:

https://github.com/zloirock/core-js

[What is the difference between isomorphic-fetch and fetch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37936715/what-is-the-difference-between-isomorphic-fetch-and-fetch)