# ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this error when I compile my code in node.js, how can I fix it?

RefernceError: fetch is not defined

[image]

This is the function I am doing, it is responsible for recovering information from a specific movie database.

```
function getMovieTitles(substr){  
  pageNumber=1;
  let url = 'https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies/search/?Title=' + substr + "&page=" + pageNumber;
  fetch(url).then((resp) => resp.json()).then(function(data) {
    let movies = data.data;
    let totPages = data.total_pages;
    let sortArray = [];
    for(let i=0; i<movies.length;i++){
        sortArray.push(data.data[i].Title);
     }
    for(let i=2; i<=totPages; i++){
           let newPage = i;
           let url1 = 'https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies/search/?Title=' + substr + "&page=" + newPage;

          fetch(url1).then(function(response) {
              var contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
              if(contentType && contentType.indexOf("application/json") !== -1) {
                return response.json().then(function(json) {
                  //console.log(json); //uncomment this console.log to see the JSON data.

                 for(let i=0; i<json.data.length;i++){
                    sortArray.push(json.data[i].Title);
                 }

                 if(i==totPages)console.log(sortArray.sort());

                });
              } else {
                console.log("Oops, we haven't got JSON!");
              }
            });

        }
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });   
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide the details on what have you tried so far?
Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) wherever required. Also please take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: `fetch` is not a standard nodejs method - you need `node-fetch`

Comment: `fetch()` was designed for the browser and then back-ported to node.js in a third party module whcih you are apparently missing.  The `request()` or `request-promise()` library is more natively built for node.js and supports a much wider range of options for node.js including streams, a zillion authentication methods, etc...

Comment: Please, don’t include an image of your error. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 844):

If you're using a version of Node prior to 18, the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is not implemented out-of-the-box and you'll need to use an external module for that, like [node-fetch](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch).

Install it in your Node application like this

```
npm install node-fetch
```

then put the line below at the top of the files where you are using the fetch API:

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";
```

---

If your application cannot be updated to use ESM (aka `import` syntax), and you need to use CommonJS (aka `require`), then stick with v2 of `node-fetch`. As per their README, [v2 will continue to receive critical bug fixes](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch#commonjs).

```bash
npm install node-fetch@2
```

and then this will work,

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
```

Comment: Following these instructions, I had to save my file with the `.mjs` extension to make it work.

Comment: The Fetch API [has been implemented](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/41749) in Node and should be released [in a year or so](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=30161964).

Comment: it is, from node v18 fetch is available at global scope

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @LukasLiesis. I made a small edit to account for the addition of the fetch API in Node 18.

Comment: 2022 UPDATE: Node released 'node version 18' which allows you to use fetch without any extra packages like 'node-fetch'.

Answer (score 97):

**This is a quick dirty fix, please try to eliminate this usage in production code.**

If `fetch` has to be accessible with a global scope

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
globalThis.fetch = fetch
```

Comment: This was the only way that I was able to get WebStorm to recognize the promise returned by `fetch` and autocomplete the available methods. Agreed that it should be avoided in production, but very helpful for local dev!

Comment: @FoxMulder900 This is how you could have still IntelliSense without having it global defined: `const nodeFetch = require('node-fetch') as typeof fetch;`

Comment: globalThis is not defined

Comment: use global.fetch = fetch @OlegAbrazhaev

Answer (score 51):

You can use [cross-fetch](https://github.com/lquixada/cross-fetch) from [@lquixada](https://github.com/lquixada)

> Platform agnostic: browsers, node or react native

**Install**

```
npm install --save cross-fetch
```

**Usage**

With promises:

```
import fetch from 'cross-fetch';
// Or just: import 'cross-fetch/polyfill';

fetch('//api.github.com/users/lquixada')
  .then(res => {
    if (res.status >= 400) {
      throw new Error("Bad response from server");
    }
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(user => {
    console.log(user);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

With async/await:

```
import fetch from 'cross-fetch';
// Or just: import 'cross-fetch/polyfill';

(async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('//api.github.com/users/lquixada');

    if (res.status >= 400) {
      throw new Error("Bad response from server");
    }

    const user = await res.json();

    console.log(user);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: This helped for metaweather api, well explained in github documentation. Thanks for Sharing

Comment: Using crossfetch's polyfill also worked for me using typescript and node and receiving the `ReferenceError: fetch is not defined` error from `amazon-cognito-identity-js`.

Answer (score 42):

If you want to avoid npm install and not running in browser, you can also use nodejs https module;

```
const https = require('https')
const url = "https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies";
https.get(url, res => {
  let data = '';
  res.on('data', chunk => {
    data += chunk;
  });
  res.on('end', () => {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data);
  })
}).on('error', err => {
  console.log(err.message);
})
```

Starting node version 18, Fetch API is available (Stable in version 21.x)
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v21.x/api/globals.html#fetch

```
// Promise version:

const url = "https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies";

fetch(url).then(res => {
    return res.json();
}).then(data => {
    console.log('DATA: ', data);
})
```

OR

```
// async/await version

const url = "https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies";

const getData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(url);

    if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();

        console.log('DATA: ', data);
    }
};
getData();
```

Comment: Just remember to add `.end()` right at the bottom of this snippet to actually start the request off. See [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_end_data_encoding_callback)

Answer (score 21):

`fetch` came to Node v17 under experimental flag `--experimental-fetch`

It will be available in Node v18 without the flag.

https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/41749#issue-1118239565

You no longer need any additional package to be installed

Comment: Node 18 is out, and it is still experimental.

Comment: I use node v 18 in my local env and `fetch` just works on the server. On Netlify with v18 however it does not work. I need node-fetch.

Answer (score 16):

**EDITED - New Solution**

To use the latest version (**3.0.0**) you must do the import like this:

```
const fetch = (url) => import('node-fetch').then(({default: fetch}) => fetch(url));
```

---

---

**Old Anwser:**

This **may not be** the best solution, but if you install this version :

```
npm install node-fetch@1.7.3
```

you can now use the line below without error's.

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use this older version instead of using the latest one, especially noting [this vulnerability](https://snyk.io/test/npm/node-fetch/1.7.3) with it?

Comment: @LW001 When I had this problem this was a quick fix I did. If you use the new version(3.0.0) , it will get 
 an error in import and then you'll get another one that says "fetch is not a function".
As you said, this version has vulnerabilities and you should always use the latest one, so I edited my answer to solve the problem.

Comment: In your code (new one) the Promise will not work. If you need to use `require` go with version 2 which will get critical updates: "If you cannot switch to ESM, please use v2 which remains compatible with CommonJS. Critical bug fixes will continue to be published for v2." `node-fetch@2`

Answer (score 15):

Node.js hasn't implemented the fetch() method, but you can use one of the external modules of this fantastic execution environment for JavaScript.

In one of the other answers, "node-fetch" is cited and that's a good choice.

In your project folder (the directory where you have the .js scripts) install that module with the command:

```
npm i node-fetch --save
```

Then use it as a constant in the script you want to execute with Node.js, something like this:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
```

Comment: require() of ES module is not supported

Comment: use `import fetch from 'node-fetch'` instead of const foo = require('foo') and add the following line to your package.json file: "type": "module".

Answer (score 11):

You should add this import in your file:

```
import * as fetch from 'node-fetch';
```

And then, run this code to add the `node-fetch`:
`$ yarn add node-fetch`

If you're working with typescript, then install node-fetch types:
`$ yarn add @types/node-fetch`

Comment: If I import in this way and use typescript, I have this error `TS2349: This expression is not callable. Type 'typeof import("/node_modules/@types/node-fetch/index")' has no call signatures.`. It works only with `require`.

Comment: run `$ yarn add @types/node-fetch` to installing node-fetch types

Comment: of course I did, it is about using es6 `import` vs `require`. seems like `node-fetch` does not support this modern import syntaxis.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use the [`isomorphic-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch) module to your `Node` project because `Node` does not contain `Fetch API` yet. For fixing this problem run below command:

```
npm install --save isomorphic-fetch es6-promise
```

After installation use below code in your project:

```
import "isomorphic-fetch"
```

Comment: Not actively maintained; has been years since the last accepted PR.

https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch/graphs/contributors

Comment: FYI, this can lead to difficult in typescript projects because this library does not provide proper types.  An easier router is to use cross-fetch which is very similar but plays nice with typescript.

For a react app where you are assuming that normal fetch will be available in the browser you can make this a dev dependency and use `import 'cross-fetch/polyfill';` in test setup to smooth the rough edges of the testing environment.

Answer (score 6):

For those also using **typescript** on **node-js** and are getting a `ReferenceError: fetch is not defined` error

`npm install` these packages:

```
    "node-fetch": "^2.3.0"
```

Then include:

```js
import Global = NodeJS.Global;
export interface GlobalWithCognitoFix extends Global {
    fetch: any
}
declare const global: GlobalWithCognitoFix;
global.fetch = require('node-fetch');
```

Comment: `amazon-cognito-identity-js` is not relevant to this question and not needed to install to solve this error. It is also not related to typescript.

Comment: Hi! So i am having exactly the same issue, but this still din't fix anything, do you have any other work around?

Comment: I'm also looking for a work-around.  Doing 

import fetch from 'node-fetch';

instead is one fix for typescript

Answer (score 5):

Best one is Axios library for fetching.
use `npm i --save axios` for installng and use it like fetch, just write axios instead of fetch and then get response in **then()**.

Comment: This is happening more in build time, while your comment is good, the problem is different to what you proposed

Answer (score 5):

It seems fetch support URL scheme with "http" or "https" for CORS request.

Install node fetch library `npm install node-fetch`, read the file and parse to json.

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const readJson = filename => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (filename.toLowerCase().endsWith(".json")) {
      fs.readFile(filename, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err)
          return
        }
        resolve(JSON.parse(data))
      })
    }
    else {
      reject(new Error("Invalid filetype, <*.json> required."))
      return
    }
  })
}

// usage
const filename = "../data.json"
readJson(filename).then(data => console.log(data)).catch(err => console.log(err.message))
```

Answer (score 5):

In HackerRank, some libraries are installed by default and some are not.

Because it is running Node.js, **the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is not installed by default**.

The best thing for you to do is to check whether the libraries are or not installed.

on the top of the exercise, there is the following:

```js
const https = require('https');
```

Please try to add this to the top as well:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
```

and then run the code.

If there is a compilation error, then it's not available, otherwise you can use `axios`, which is a good alternative to `fetch`

To use it with `then`, you can:

```js
function getMovieTitles(substr){
  axios.get(url)
    .then(function(response){
      console.log(response.data);
    })
}
```

or taking advantage of the `async/await`

```js
async function getMovieTitles(substr){
  let response = await axios.get(url)
  console.log(response.data);
}
```

Comment: axios is not the mdn standard fetch. question doesn't mention alt

Answer (score 5):

In node.js you can use : **[node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)** package

```
npm i node-fetch
```

then :

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
```

here is a full sample in (nodejs) :

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const fetchData = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/col"); // fetch() returns a promise, so we need to wait for it

  const country = await res.json(); // res is now only an HTTP response, so we need to call res.json()

  console.log(country); // Columbia's data will be logged to the dev console
};

fetchData();
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the related github [issue](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-request/issues/168)
This bug is related to the 2.0.0 version, you can solve it by simply upgrading to version 2.1.0.
You can run
`npm i graphql-request@2.1.0-next.1`

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this error when I deployed my docker instance to production. It was weird to see the application failed with the error in this question.

I realised the Dockerfile had `FROM node:16.13.1` and my system node version was `20.3.1`.

If you don't want to use 'node-fetch' as shown in many answers and use 'fetch' ensure that you're using node version 18 or above. The reference error is likely because your node version is less than 18.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me in Node.js 12.x:

```
npm i node-fetch;
```

to initialize the Dropbox instance:

```
var Dropbox = require("dropbox").Dropbox;
var dbx = new Dropbox({
   accessToken: <your access token>,
   fetch: require("node-fetch")    
});
```

to e.g. upload a content (an asynchronous method used in this case):

```
await dbx.filesUpload({
  contents: <your content>,
  path: <file path>
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
const nodeFetch = require('node-fetch') as typeof fetch;
```

Answer (score 2):

```bash
npm i node-fetch
```

Once installed, in your JavaScript file:

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";
```

Lastly make this change `package.json` file:

```
"type": "module"
```

Answer (score 1):

For me these are looking more simple.

```
npm install node-fetch
```

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error in a Jest test when using native fetch in Node.js version 18(.15.0).

Upgrading to the latest version of Jest (in my case from 27.5.1 to 29.5.0) fixed the issue:

```
npm install jest@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

There are actually a lot of different libraries for making `fetch` available in the browser.

The main ones I'm aware of are:

- [node-fetch](https://openbase.com/js/node-fetch)
- [cross-fetch](https://openbase.com/js/cross-fetch)
- [whatwg-fetch](https://openbase.com/js/whatwg-fetch)
- [isomorphic-fetch](https://openbase.com/js/isomorphic-fetch)

I currently use node-fetch, and it has worked fine, but I don't really know which one is "the best". (though the openbase.com pages I linked to provide some metadata on usage [eg. Github stars, npm downloads], which can help)

Answer (score -1):

Solution without installations

[image]

**Method 1**

```
import { PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) { 
    // constructor code
}

ngOnInit() {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
        // Client only code. Any javascript base functions
    }
    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
        // Server only code. Any javascript base functions
    }
}
```

**Method 2**

```
import {  PLATFORM_ID} from '@angular/core';
    import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-navigation',
      templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.scss'],
      changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    })
    export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {
      private isBrowser: boolean = false;
    
      constructor(
        @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
      ) {
        this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
      }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
          if (this.isBrowser) {
            fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((json) => console.log(json));
            }
        }
      }
```

[DEMO - JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ssuryar/vdfxwe67/2/) - Open console to view the fetch api service working

Answer (score -2):

Just make your app.js file Extension as app.mjs and the problem will be solved!!!:)

Answer (score -3):

Might sound silly but I simply called `npm i node-fetch --save` in the wrong project. Make sure you are in the correct directory.

Comment: You must not `--save` what is required only for tests. Use `--save-dev` instead.

Answer (score -3):

If need install:

```
npm install --save global-fetch
```

then

```
var fetch = require("node-fetch");
```

Comment: Is it `global-fetch` or `node-fetch`?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).