# Getting ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, redux-saga, universal

In my Saga test for my react native application (that does work correctly) I have added the following test that calls a function that perform a POST http call (doScan).

```
describe('Scan the product and register the scanning action', () => {
  const it = sagaHelper(scanProductSaga(scanProductAction(item)));

  it('logscan via ASL', (result) => {
    expect(result).toEqual(cps(ASLogger.logScan, xxx));
    return logScanResult;
  });

  it('should register the product', (result) => {
    expect(result).toEqual(call(doScan, logScanResult));
  });
});
```

Separate file:

```
const doScan = scanObj =>
  toJSON(fetch('https://xxxx.xxxxxx.com/logger/scans', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers(CONTENT_TYPE_HEADERS),
    body: JSON.stringify(scanObj),
  }));
```

Note: the fetch function is from 'react-native-interfaces.js' within the react-native library. The test fails and the error is caused by the following exception :

```
ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
      at doScan (/Users/andy/WebstormProjects/ASAP/api/index.js:81:11)....
```

What can cause such issue? What the solution may be?

Answer (score 6):

react-native has `fetch` default, but test environment on node.js does not have `fetch`.

You can import `fetch` like following at the top of test code.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
```

---

The file react-native-interface.js only declare the type of `fetch`.

```
declare var fetch: any;
```

Answer (score 3):

For some cases, in a universal application for both, client and server the maintainers have to use [`isomorphic-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch) module to their `Node` project because of `Node` does not contain `Fetch API` yet. For more information read [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433783/referenceerror-fetch-is-not-defined)

But in this special case, hence, `React Native`, it is some different, Because, in the mobile device area, there is no `V8`, `SpiderMonkey` or `Node`. There is [`JavaScriptCore`](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/JavaScriptCore). So, for this new situation should be used [`react-native-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fetch).

It is a little different, install it with below code:

```
npm install react-native-fetch
```

And then, use it like a `JSX` component:

```
import Fetch from 'react-native-fetch'
...
  <Fetch
      url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"
      retries={3}
      timeout={3000}
      onResponse={async (res) => {
        const json = await res.json()
        console.log(json)
      }}
      onError={console.error}
  />
```

It's so new, but lovely.