# angular universal, d3, ERROR ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

Tags: angular, angular-universal

This [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433783/referenceerror-fetch-is-not-defined) also occurs in angular `universal`:

[image]

I try to `install node-fetch-polyfill` and import it.

```
//npm install node-fetch-polyfill

import * as fetch from "node-fetch-polyfill"; 

ngOnInit() {
    if (typeof fetch !== 'function') {
      (global as any).fetch = fetch;
    }
}
```

But it still doesn't work, I don't use `fetch` directly in my code.

Comment: The documentation seems to suggest this is meant to be used with node.js. Are you sure it supports Angular ?

Comment: @DelwynPinto I'm not sure, but this is the solution I can find so far.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation said:

> A light-weight module that brings window.fetch to Node.js

So I assume you would like to use the fetch only in server, so you should check whether you are on server or on client. Like this for eg:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof fetch !== 'function') {
  (global as any).fetch = fetch;
}
```

BUT! The best if you use PLATFORM_ID!

```
import { PLATFORM_ID, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser} from '@angular/common';
export class MyComponent {
    isBrowser: boolean;
    constructor(
        @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: string) {
            this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
    }
    ngOnInit() {
       if (!this.isBrowser && typeof fetch !== 'function') {
        ...
     }
```