# fetch is not defined when access another file

Tags: javascript, arrays, fetch

I' trying to use fetch to access data in other file but it keeps return

```
ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
```

```
      const getData = async () => {
      const fetchedData = await fetch("./dino.json");
      const data = await fetchedData.json();
      return data.Dinos;
    };
    getData().then(data => {
      console.log(data); // will print the array
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
```

I am looking at this [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) but it did not specify that if we need install anything

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReferenceError: fetch is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433783/referenceerror-fetch-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 3):

You are probably using `node` where `fetch` is not defined, it's only available by default in a browser. U can install it as a `npm` package [node-fetch](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch).

Answer (score 0):

As Marcos said, If you are using a `node`, the fetch method will not be available. And to use it, you need to install the "node-fetch" package and then import to use it.

After using "node-fetch", you'll get another error `" Only absolute URLs are supported"`, to fix that, you need to give the full URL of the file.

**Here is the example code:**

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch' 

const getData = async () => {
      const fetchedData = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/dino.json");
      const data = await fetchedData.json();
      return data.Dinos;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade from Node.js 18 or higher, you won't get the error anymore. The versions include an experimental globally available Fetch API. See the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/de/blog/announcements/v18-release-announce/#fetch-experimental) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happens because you are using a node version older than 18 which doesn't include "fetch".

You can either install the dependency as stated in other responses or update your node version.