# Why do I get this error while trying to insert data to SQL Server with NodeJS and Tedious?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, tedious

Working in a NodeJS that saves data to a SQL Server Database, it must save data from an array of objects but when I run it I get this error, just looked here and documentation but I don't really understand how to fix it, any help is welcomed. This is the error:

```
PS D:\Users\****\****\****\****\****> node appb.js
Successful connection
events.js:135
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('listener', 'Function', listener);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type function. Received type string ('row')
```

And this is my app.js:

Connection:

```
var Connection = require("tedious").Connection;
var lstValid = [];

var config = {
  server: "SERVER",
  authentication: {
    type: "default",
    options: {
      userName: "USERNAME",
      password: "PASSWORD",
    },
  },
  options: {
    encrypt: true,
    database: "DATABASE",
    instanceName: 'INSTANCENAME'
  },
};
var connection = new Connection(config);
connection.on("connect", function (err) {
  console.log("Successful connection");
  executeStatement1();
});

connection.connect();
```

and here's where I insert data:

```
async function calcWeather() {
  const info = await fetch("../json/data.json")
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    });
  for (var i in info) {
    const _idOficina = info[i][0].IdOficina;
    const lat = info[i][0].latjson;
    const long = info[i][0].lonjson;
    const base = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&appid=${api_key}&units=metric&lang=sp`;
    fetch(base)
      .then((responses) => {
        return responses.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        var myObject = {
          Id_Oficina: _idOficina,
          // Other thins in myObject
        };
        // validation and saving data to array
        if (myObject.Temperatura < 99) {
          lstValid.push(myObject);
        }
      });
  }
}
var Request = require("tedious").Request;
var TYPES = require("tedious").TYPES;

function executeStatement1() {
  calcWeather();
  for (var m = 0; m <= lstValid.length; m++) {
    Request = new Request(
      "INSERT INTO TB_BI_CSL_RegistroTemperaturaXidOdicina (IdOficina, Humedad, Nubes, Sensacion, Temperatura, Descripcion) VALUES (@IdOficina, @Humedad, @Nubes, @Sensacion, @Temperatura)",
      function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Couldn't insert data: " + err);
        }
      }
    );
    Request.addParameter("IdOficina", TYPES.SmallInt, lstValid[m]);
    // Other things inserted
    Request.on('requestCompleted',"row", function (columns) {
      columns.forEach(function (column) {
        if (column.value === null) {
          console.log("NULL");
        } else {
          console.log("Product id of inserted item is " + column.value);
        }
      });
    });
    Request.on("requestCompleted", function (rowCount, more) {
      connection.close();
    });
    connection.execSql(Request);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that there are too many parameters to the `request.on(...)` method, i.e.:

```js
Request.on('requestCompleted',"row", function (columns)
```

Should probably be:

```js
Request.on("row", function (columns)
```

Comment: sorry mate, I couldn't answer until now cause my horrible internet, I just did what you said and know I get ```Couldn't insert data: Error: Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the Connecting state
(node:7452) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: fetch is not defined```and looking for how to solve this, I saw I had to put what I already had :c

Comment: Regarding the 'fetch is not defined' portion of the error, this other stack answer may address that issue: [ReferenceError: fetch is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48433898/177260) tldr; Fetch is not included by default on Node and must be included. Does that apply here?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The error says the JavaScript function received arguments that were different than expected:

`...ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('listener', 'Function', listener);`

If it has never worked, the function was likely mistyped. (If it has worked, it could be bad data coming in)

The next message gives a further information:

```
"...The "listener" argument must be of type function. Received type string ('row')"
```

A JavaScript function to do work was expected, but it received a simple string 'row' instead.

```
events.js:135
```

This means the error happened in the file 'events.js' on or before line 135.

The [TediusJs API Request Docs](http://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/api-request.html#event_row), provides a reference example:

```
request.on('row', function (columns) { /* code to process rows */ });
```

In your example we find:

```
Request.on('requestCompleted',"row", function (columns) {
```

Most likely it should be:

```
Request.on("row", function (columns) {
```

Although I am not positive which line in your example is line 135.

Comment: Sorry for answering so late mate, I did what you said and know I get ```Couldn't insert data: Error: Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the Connecting state
(node:9024) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: fetch is not defined``` any ideas what it could be?