# Theta js. How use it with Node JS

Tags: node.js, blockchain

I create a Theta Token wallet, get its balance with theta.js (@thetalabs/theta-js) in Node Js app. But when I try to get a transaction, I get error: fetch is undefined. I thing, theta.js uses fetch. How can I use theta js in Node.js apps?
I tried add node-fetch lib, but it doesn't help me.

Maybe, there is another lib for Node apps with theta?

Comment: show us whatu have tried

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433783/referenceerror-fetch-is-not-defined

Comment: import fetch from 'node-fetch', globalThis.fetch = fetch  - thats works, thanks!

Comment: I am glad that it solved your issue. Do upvote it...if it helped you. @Anton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use
`import fetch from 'node-fetch'; globalThis.fetch = fetch;`
Since you need a global scope to use fetch here.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me....install `isomorphic-fetch` using the command:

```
npm i isomorphic-fetch
```

and then require it in your file using:

```
const fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch')
```

It will work..check this out.