# fetch(url).then() in single js file

Tags: javascript

how can i invoke fetch method inside single js file?
I created file with content

```
    const fetch = require("fetch").fetchUrl
 fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1").then(res =>
        res.json()).then(d => {console.log(d)
        })
```

then i invoke this

```
node fetch.js
```

but receiving error

> fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1").then(res =>
> ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
> at Object. (C:\repo\rust\fetch.js:2:55)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReferenceError: fetch is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433783/referenceerror-fetch-is-not-defined)

Comment: which version of node are you using?

Comment: a7md0 - nope
i use 16.14

Comment: That's simply not how that particular implementation of `fetch` that you've chosen works. Have you tried reading the manual? https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch

Comment: You'll have to install node-fetch

Comment: i have installed

Comment: To make this clear again: there's [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch), which implements the [`fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) for node. That would allow you to use `.then`. But that's not what you have installed. You have installed the package [`fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch), which is a different package with a different API which does *not* use `.then`. Install the package you actually want and read its manual to learn how to use it correctly.

Comment: i've installed both

Comment: So…? When you try to use each exactly as documented, what happens…?

Answer (score 0):

`fetchUrl` function don't work that way.

Try this

```
 const fetch = require("fetch").fetchUrl('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',  function(error, meta, body){
       console.log(body.toString());
   })
```

Comment: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'fetch'.ts(2451)
lib.dom.d.ts(18281, 18): 'fetch' was also declared here.

Comment: When Using `fetchUrl` you will need to follow this: 
- url is the url to fetch
- options is an optional options object
- callback is the callback to run - callback(error, meta, body)

Comment: Show me your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
    const fetch = require('node-fetch');
    
    let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
    
    let settings = { method: "Get" };

    fetch(url, settings)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
      });
```

Comment: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\repo\rust\node_modules\node-fetch\src\index.js from C:\repo\rust\fetch.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in C:\repo\rust\fetch.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\repo\rust\fetch.js:1:15) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

im not sure if some of you was reading topic, but most of answers were useless.
i've asked chat gpt and only thing i had to do was install older version of node-fetch

```
npm i node-fetch@2.6.1
```

and code like in my question or sth like this will work

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
fetch(url)
.then(res => res.json())
.then((json) => {
  console.log(json);
});
```