# Call a rest webservice inside Playwright test script

Tags: playwright

I'm starting to learn typescript and Playwright, and I need to make a GET call inside a Playwright test.

This call is for creating a session and will return a json with a SESSION_ID that I'll include later in the URL.

Thanks,
Jose.

> I've tried by adding jquery dependences: `npm i --save-dev @types/jquery`, but running this code:

```js
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test('test', async ({ page }) => {
  var settings = {
    "url": "http://xxxxxx.yyyyyy.com:8080/ords/hero_ords/heroapps/v1/mysession",
    "method": "GET",
    "timeout": 0,
  };

  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

I get this error: `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Thanks,
Jose.

Comment: `$.ajax` is a jQuery call. JavaScript and TypeScript have the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_json_data) that does the same thing without requiring extra libraries, eg `var resp=await fetch("http://....");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.ajax` is a jQuery call. JavaScript and TypeScript have the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_json_data) that does the same thing without requiring extra libraries and works with `await:

```
var response=await fetch(url);
var data=await response.json();
```

**Running on Node**

Node.js versions before 18 didn't support the Fetch API. Trying to use it results in `ReferenceError: fetch is not defined`. The solution, described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433783/referenceerror-fetch-is-not-defined) is to either use a newer Node version or install the `node-fetch` package with:

```
npm install node-fetch
```

The best option is to use Node 18. By now, Node 18 is [the only version in active support](https://endoflife.date/nodejs). It's an LTS version supported until 2025. Node 17 is already out of support and the previous LTS version, 16, is in Security support which expires in September 2023

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick support. Using fetch I get "ReferenceError: fetch is not defined"

Comment: How are you running the test? `fetch` is a built-in JavaScript function but Node.js versions before 18 didn't support it. There's a related  [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433783/referenceerror-fetch-is-not-defined). The solution is to either use a recent Node version or add the `node-fetch` package

Comment: Upgraded from node 14 to node 18.15.0 solved my issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do I mark this thread as answered by you? (I'm pretty newbie with StackOverflow)