# Google's Gemini for Nodejs results in error ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

Tags: google-gemini

I am trying Google's Gemini model in Node js as suggested in their documentation [here](https://ai.google.dev/tutorials/node_quickstart#:%7E:text=input%2C%20use%20the%20gemini%2Dpro%20model%0A%C2%A0%20const%20model%20%3D-,genAI.getGenerativeModel,-(%7B%20model%3A%20%22gemini%2Dpro%22%7D)%3B%0A%0A%C2%A0%20const%20prompt)

However, when I executed their sample code in my node application, i receive the following error:

ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

This is the code block i'm trying:

```
const model = genAI.getGenerativeModel({ model: "gemini-pro"});
const prompt = "Write a story about a magic backpack."
const result = await model.generateContent(prompt);
const response = await result.response;
const text = response.text();
console.log(text);
```

Anyone know how the issue?

Followed exactly what the documentation [example](https://ai.google.dev/tutorials/node_quickstart#:%7E:text=input%2C%20use%20the%20gemini%2Dpro%20model%0A%C2%A0%20const%20model%20%3D-,genAI.getGenerativeModel,-(%7B%20model%3A%20%22gemini%2Dpro%22%7D)%3B%0A%0A%C2%A0%20const%20prompt)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full code.

Comment: What's your node version? fetch required node 18 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433783/referenceerror-fetch-is-not-defined

Comment: I am using Node 16. However, I installed node-fetch, which still resulted in the same error. I don't see anywhere in Google's documentation that I'd need node 18 in order to use @google/generative-ai

Comment: If you're using a version of Node prior to 18, the `fetch` API is not implemented out-of-the-box and you'll need to use an external module for that, like `node-fetch`. See this  [ReferenceError: fetch is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433783/referenceerror-fetch-is-not-defined)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReferenceError: fetch is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433783/referenceerror-fetch-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 1):

you have to use node version minimum 18 or later. it's work

Comment: this was my issue, I was using node version 16